# WordPress Payment link will not transform PHP vars into values

Tags: shortcode

My WordPress site runs with WP 4.3 + Avada 3.8.6.1 Theme.
On a subscription page there are several payment buttons with links to a PsP.

I have to know the ID - Name - Email from each user.

The page show the `$GLOBALS` correct when use shortcodes `[insert_php]`.

If I echo the `$GLOBALS` within `[insert_php]` it works great on the page.

```
[insert_php]echo $GLOBALS['user_id'];[/insert_php]
```

result: 8922 // userid

```
[insert_php]echo $GLOBALS['user_lastname'];[/insert_php]
```

result: customer lastname

Problem is the url link. I have tried several possibilities to get the PHP $GLOBALS into the link. See below the result of an url link.

```
https://www.pay.nl/payment/SL-9839-2480/3Lc2c5c/?amount_min=7497&extra1%5BCID%5d=[insert_php]echo $GLOBALS[‘user_id’];[/insert_php]&extra2%5BNaam%5D=[insert_php]echo $GLOBALS[‘user_lastname’];[/insert_php]&extra3%5BEmail%5D=[insert_php]echo $GLOBALS[‘user_email’];[/insert_php]
```

Avada code on page:

```
[pricing_footer][button link=[insert_php]echo "https://www.pay.nl/payment/SL-9839-2480/3Lc2c5c/?amount_min=7497&extra1%5BCID%5d=" . $GLOBALS[‘user_id’] . "&extra2%5BNaam%5D=" . $GLOBALS[‘user_lastname’] . "&extra3%5BEmail%5D=" . $GLOBALS[‘user_email’][/insert_php] color="default" size="small" type="flat"[/pricing_footer]
```

Comment: Please share your code where you assign the variables to the URL

Comment: Oh I see. You do it from the WP editor and you use a shortcode to pass php code right?

Comment: Please, note that you are trying to execute PHP directly into the content editor and the editor is not intended for that and it is very bad practice. Additionally, what you are trying to do is not possible without using third party plugins, like you are already doing ([pricing_footer], [insert_php] and so on are not from WordPress, so they are from third party plugins). [You must know that questions that require knowledge about third party plugins/themes are off-topic here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). It is better if you ask to the support team of that plugin/theme.

Comment: I fixed the _wrong quotes_ for `$GLOBALS[‘user_id’]` in the upper part (left them in for comparison in the bottom code parts. Please check that and please file a edit and explain what @cybmeta asked: Are you trying to execute PHP from within the WordPress admin UI TinyMCE editor? Thansk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correct this should work but as cybmeta said ask the support team of the theme/plugin.

```
[insert_php]echo "https://www.pay.nl/payment/SL-9839-2480/3Lc2c5c/?amount_min=7497&extra1%5BCID%5d=" . $GLOBALS[‘user_id’] . "&extra2%5BNaam%5D=" . $GLOBALS[‘user_lastname’] . "&extra3%5BEmail%5D=" . $GLOBALS[‘user_email’][/insert_php]
```

Comment: I have try to solution of Laxmana without success. The complete link is disappaered when using that code.
I will add the avada code in my question so you can see how it is setup.

Comment: I solved it:
&extra1%5BCID%5D=[insert_php] echo $GLOBALS['user_id'] ; [/insert_php]&extra2%5BNaam%5D=[insert_php] echo $GLOBALS['user_lastname'] ; [/insert_php]&extra3%5BEmail%5D=[insert_php] echo $GLOBALS['user_email'] ; [/insert_php]

Comment: My fault was: to change text within the visual environment of avada theme text. I had todo it in the text environment. After I did this it was running.